# Select search return with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am building a multi-step local search engine with powershell that also allows you to email selected pieces of information.

I have got the search engine part down and the email part down, I just need to get the select part down.

So right now, you open the program and it prompts you to search for what you want. If I put in the query `when`, this is what is returned:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         1/25/2017   3:29 PM    8357890 01 - Kiss Me When I'm Down.mp3
-a---         1/24/2017   2:15 PM    7189290 09 - When You Love Someone.mp3
```

Now the goal is to select let's say `01 - Kiss Me When I'm Down.mp3`, because I'm then going to put that into an `$attachment` variable, which will then send the song as an attachment. Is this achievable?

**EDIT for clarity:**

I've tried working with `Select-Object` to do this, but I can't get it to allow the user to select the song that they want. That is the goal of this, to allow the user to select the input they want.

Comment: `dir|ogv -PassThru`

Comment: @PetSerAl That looks like just what I need, the only issue is I'm getting a "parameter cannot be found" error for -PassThru

Comment: PowerShell version?

Comment: @PetSerAl PS v2

Comment: Then you out of luck, because `Out-GridView -PassThru` required at least v3. You probably have to use some solution based on `PromptForChoice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an inelegant solution that adds an `Index` `NoteProperty` using the `Add-Member` cmdlet. As an example I used `Get-ChildItem` results:

```
$Items = Get-ChildItem C:\
$Index = 1
$Count = $Items.Count
foreach ($Item in $Items) {
    $Item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Index" -Value $Index
    $Index++
}
$Items | Select-Object Index, Attributes, LastWriteTime, Name | Out-Host
$Input = Read-Host "Select an item by index (1 to $Count)"
$Selected = $Items[$Input - 1]
Write-Host "You have selected $Selected"
```

Comment: You learn something every day!  I didn't know you could add note properties to existing "system returned" objects.  Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

I realise some good answers have been given, but the OP's post got me thinking about extracting the meta data for the MP3s...:

```
function getMP3Details() {

    param ( [System.IO.FileInfo] $mp3file = $null )

    [System.__ComObject] $Local:objShell    = $null;
    [System.__ComObject] $Local:objFolder   = $null;
    [System.__ComObject] $Local:objFile     = $null;
    [HashTable]          $Local:objTags     = @{ 0 = 'Name'; 1 = 'Size'; 13 = 'Artists'; 14 = 'Album'; 15 = 'Year'; 16 = 'Genre'; 20 = 'Authors'; 21 = 'Title'; 28 = 'Bit Rate'; }
    [Int32]              $Local:intTagIndex = 0;
    [String]             $Local:strTagName  = '';
    [String]             $Local:strTagValue = '';
    [PSCustomObject]     $Local:objOutput   = $null;

    try {
        if ( $mp3file -ne $null ) {

            $objShell  = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application;
            $objFolder = $objShell.NameSpace( $mp3file.DirectoryName );
            $objFile   = $objFolder.ParseName( $mp3file.Name );
            $objOutput = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject;

            foreach ( $intTagIndex in ($objTags.Keys | Sort-Object) ) {
                $strTagName  = $objTags[$intTagIndex];
                $strTagValue = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf( $objFile, $intTagIndex );
                Add-Member -InputObject $objOutput -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $strTagName -Value ( [String] ($strTagValue -replace '[^ -~]', '') );
            } #foreach

            Write-Output -InputObject $objOutput;

        } #if
    } #try
    catch [System.Exception] {
        # Do something.
        'Error';
    } #catch

return;
}

[String]           $Local:strFolder        = '<PATH TO ALBUM>';
[PSCustomObject[]] $Local:arrMP3Tracks     = @();
[PSCustomObject]   $Local:objSelectedTrack = $null;

try {
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $strFolder -File -Filter *.mp3 | Foreach-Object {
        $arrMP3Tracks += getMP3Details -mp3file $_;
    } #Foreach-Object
$objSelectedTrack = $arrMP3Tracks | Out-GridView -PassThru;
} #try
catch [System.Exception] {
    # Do something.
    'Error';
} #catch

exit 0;
```

Comment: Just a tiny comment, your code is extremely well formatted, but trailing `;`s are not needed : ) but maybe you just need them somehow?

Comment: Old habits...  plus they keep me sane!